# Git - How to exclude .gitignore file during checkout from bare repository?

Tags: git, version-control, git-bash

I am working on a website locally.
I turned the folder containing its files into a repository with a working tree.

Afterwards, I push the changes to a bare "remote" repository which is also just a folder in the local disk.

I created a `post-receive` hook in the "remote" repository which checkouts to a certain local folder which simulates the web root in a server every time I push into the bare repository.

However, because I have a `.gitignore` file in the working tree, it is also checked out to what's supposed to be the "live" website.

How do I exclude the `.gitignore` file during checkout?
Any other tips are welcome.

Comment: Why does it matter if the live website has a gitignore file in it? are you working with git on the live website?

Comment: What files are being ignored? If they're related to the project (for example your app's cache or node_modules folder) they should be ignored. If they're just local system files (like .DS_store or any cache files created by your editor), you can use `.git/excludes` instead, which is not committed to the repository.

Comment: I just don't want the .gitignore file to be in the web root because I don't think it should be there. And also, even if it's just a local web root, I would like to do it as I would do if I am actually pushing to the live server. Those were config files. I just tried to use .gitignore so that it would be more flexible in case there will be more people to work on this project in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `post-receive` hook is a script; it can amended to include additional step:

- checkout the repository to local folder
- delete the `.gitignore` in said local folder

That way, you always end up with the latest content, *without* the unwanted `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Thanks man. An rm and the file path in the post-receive is all it took.